# CASCADE AND RESTRICT are DDL or DML

Tags: sql, ddl, cascade, restriction, dml

I don't know If this question is valid or not. Yesterday I attended an interview at Deloitte (Mumbai, India) on JAVA, SPRING, HIBERNATE and SQL database. The interviewer asked me this question, whether the `CASCADE` and `RESTRICT` are DDL/DML/DCL? I answered him like, these are DDL command as used with `CREATE` clause while creating table structures. It impacts the foreign key relations If performed. A little more I explained but he was not quite satisfied with my answer. I did not find much about this on internet. Even the google gives me like -

DDL - CREATE, ALTER, DROP, TRUNCATE

DML - SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

But no information on my question. Could someone please explain me here? If `CASCADE` and `RESTRICT` are DDL/DML commands with reason(s)?

Comment: CASCADE and RESTRICT are not commands...

Comment: So this is not a valid question?

Comment: They are _options_ to (some) DDL statements.

Comment: Well, It makes sense.